# Excessive server I/O rate is a symptom of excessive memory usage?

Tags: apache-2.2, memory

I'm learning to manage a VPS LAMP server.  I noticed that whenever Apache consumes more RAM than is allotted, the server disk I/O rate jumps from a negligible value to a big value like 3k/hour.

Why is this so?  What exactly is happening?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would have to guess that this is because you have a [swapfile/partition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Page_file) setup and the system is swapping.